# Pythonic dir(module_name) in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

To get all available functions from module in Python - pythonistas doing this:

```
print(dir(module_name))
```

But how nimjas (*ninja like*) get this kind of information ?

Additional question: 
If python learners - pythonistas 
And rust learners - rustarians 
Nim --> Nimjas ? :)

Comment: I think we are nimmers.

Comment: I prefer Nimions

Comment: and rust users are rustaceans, not rustarians

Comment: Well, right now I'm more like nimion who want to be nimja in the future :D

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to **retrieve all symbols' names of a module**, which as far as I know **is not possible in Nim** (not yet, at least). There is still an open Pull Request to add this feature, but it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/9560

More information about this in a thread from the Nim forum: https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/7012

---

However, if you need it for **objects**, it is possible to use both [`typeinfo.fields`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/typeinfo.html#fields.i%2CAny) and [`iterators.fieldPairs`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/iterators.html#fieldPairs.i%2CS%2CT) (note: **modules are not objects in Nim**).

Example code for `typeinfo.fields`:

```
import typeinfo

type MyObj = object
  a: string
  b: int

var obj = MyObj(a: "asd", b: 123)

for (name, _) in fields(obj.toAny):
  echo name ## will echo "a" and "b"
```

Example code for `iterators.fieldPairs`:

```
type MyObj = object
  a: string
  b: int

var obj = MyObj(a: "asd", b: 123)

for name, value in obj.fieldPairs:
  echo name, ": ", value
```

⚠️ **Note that when using `fieldPairs`, loop is actually unrolled, as written on official documentation.**

Here's an example of `fieldPairs` used in stdlib (`json`): [lib/pure/json.nim](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/c17baaefbcff5c207a4e95242fa0790e64ca6c8c/lib/pure/json.nim#L397).

Answer (score 2):

Listing the api of a module for humans is a job for [documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/docgen.html)

Compile-time reflection of this sort is in general possible with a macro that acts upon `parseStmt(staticRead("/path/to/module"))`

[Here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Reflection/List_methods#Nim) is my answer to this question on rosettacode.

The reason why this sort of spooky-action-at-a-distance isn't made easier by Nim is philosophical rather than technical -- allowing macros to perform arbitrary transformations on source code is a 'with great power comes great responsibility' situation.

with

```
someMacro:
  statement 1
statement 2
```

it's clear what can and can't be transformed by `someMacro`; anything less explicit makes code harder to reason about.